# SQL to extract spcial charcters oracle 11g

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, validation

I have a requirement where I need to get full data having special characters including few exceptions.I tried using `REGEXP_LIKE (STATE,'[^A-Za-z0-9, ]')`
but was not able to come up with results.

1)  The following are key fields that cannot be Blank or have Special Characters.

a.  Name1

b.  Name2

c.  Contact1

d.  Address1

e.  Address2

f.  City

g.  ST

h.  Zip

2)  Special Characters that are not allowed by vendor include

```
, . / ? < > ; : ‘ “ [ ] \ | { } ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) - _ = +
```

Exception #1 - Name1,Name2,Contact1 fields allow following `- ‘ .`

Exception #2 - Address1,Address2 allow following  `# /`

select query:

```
 select Name1, Name2, Contact1, Address1, Address2, City, STATE, Zip 
 from tableA
```

Comment: A table has _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: oracle 11g...SQL developer

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to *find all rows with special characters*, right? Try this.

```
select Name1, Name2, Contact1, Address1, Address2, City, STATE, Zip 
 from tableA
 where regexp_instr(name1 || name2 || contact1, '[^.[:alnum:], -'']') > 0
   or regexp_instr(address1 || address2, '[^[:alnum:], #/]') > 0
   or regexp_instr(city || state || zip, '[^[:alnum:], ]') > 0
```

I'm suggesting using `[:alnum:]` here because [if you have NLS_SORT set, `A-Z` can behave unpredictably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271778/oracles-puzzling-behaviour-with-nls-sort-and-a-simple-regexp-like). If you're not worried about that, `A-Za-z0-9` works pretty similarly.