# regexp_replace() - maybe collation issue

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace, nls-sort

My `regexp_replace` does not remove Umlauts as expected. I thought this was because of the collation but my test did show differently. So, as far as I understand it, `ü` should not be part of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Apparently it is though:

```sql
select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','NLS_SORT') from dual;
select decode('ü','u',0,1) from dual;
select regexp_replace('ABcdäü~~~---  Ø asdsad 123 /() ´´´', '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '') x from dual;

begin

  if 'ü' > 'z' then
    dbms_output.PUT_LINE(1);
  else
    dbms_output.PUT_LINE(0);
  end if;
        
  if 'ü' > 'Z' then
    dbms_output.PUT_LINE(1);
  else
    dbms_output.PUT_LINE(0);
  end if;
        
  if 'ü' > '9' then
    dbms_output.PUT_LINE(1);
  else
    dbms_output.PUT_LINE(0);
  end if;

end;
```

Results:

```
German
1
ABcdäüØasdsad123
1
1
1
```

Comment: Linking [Oracle's puzzling behaviour with NLS_SORT and a simple REGEXP_LIKE()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1271778/4299358). Your regex is almost redundant, because the alphabet in your session is already `aAbBcC...uUüÜ...zZ`. You could avoid by not using ranges in your regex - use instead `[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So as far as I understand it ü should not be part

It depends from `nls_session_parameters`. There are two params:

```sql
SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters WHERE parameter IN ('NLS_COMP', 'NLS_SORT');
```

- NLS_COMP = how to compare characters (`ANSI`, `BINARY`, `LINGUISTIC`)
- NLS_SORT = order of characters (`BINARY`, e.g. `GERMAN`, `GERMAN_CI`, `GERMAN_AI`) - `_CI` means **c**ase **i**nsensitive, `_AI` means **a**ccent **i**nsensitive

Because in your session `NLS_SORT` is set to `GERMAN` the letter `ü` is between `a` and `z`.

```sql
alter session set NLS_SORT=BINARY
```

...and the regexp will remove Umlauts.

Comment: ah, because my nls_comp is binary I get the result that     if 'ü' > 'z' then... 1. Thank you!

Comment: One more question: I thought I could change this specifically for this statement with 
    select regexp_replace('ABcdäü~~~---  Ø asdsad 123 /() ´´´', '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '') x from dual x order by x desc
    COLLATE  BINARY ;
However this will not execute. Can you check?

Comment: You should set this nls_sort for a session. But if want to replace accented characters with normal we can convert it to ACSCI. `select CONVERT('ABcdäü~~~---  Ø asdsad 123 /() ´´´', 'US7ASCII') from dual;`